# Angular / Bootstrap 4 : multiple cards in multiple rows

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm trying to display multiple bootstrap cards in two rows, I getting the cards in the second row placed above the first ! can someone take a look and help please ?

```
 <div class="row">
    <p class="list-spectacle-title">Spectacles dans ce théâtre</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center shows-list">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <app-show-card></app-show-card>

    </div>
  </div>
```

**sass**

```
.shows-list 
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap


.shows-list > div[class*='col-']
  display: flex
```

[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgnkK.png)

Comment: its quite difficult to tell from this without complete css. 
Can you create a stackblitz with this example ?
By any chance is there a height or max-height on parent div?

Comment: question edited

Comment: can you try removing the row class from the div and see what happens

Comment: nothing happen ! @user8351493

Comment: try `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;`

Comment: @Nikhil that does not work properly, cards in the first line above the the other in the second, there is no space between the first row and the second ( which i didn't create ! that should be automatically defined when  the row reaches the sum of 12 columns ! what do you think ?

Comment: That should be some CSS changes. Hard to tell exactly what is going on unless you give us more code to reproduce the problem, preferably a link to the demo on sites like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/).

Comment: Using what you've provided us here looks to be working just fine https://codepen.io/plumwd/pen/bGbeVMx